# How to parse a json dumped python dict as javascript object in django template

Tags: jquery, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a python code which converts the normal dict into JSON as follows

```
groups = {
    'g_1': [
        {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}, 
        {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}
    ], 
    'g_2': [
        {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}, 
        {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}
    ]
}
```

I have used json.dumps to convert that to a json as follows

```
import json
groups = json.dumps(groups)
```

I want to read the data in javascript as an object. How to I access it?

I tried `var groups=JSON.parse({{ groups }})` it didn't work out. 
Help me in parsing the data as javascript object.

Comment: Did any of the following answers, satisfied you? If so, please accept one. Its a good practice in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

`var groups = JSON.parse('{{ groups|safe }}');`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var groups = JSON && JSON.parse({{ groups }})|| $.parseJSON({{ groups }});
```

Comment: Still wont work for me. The code would print out something like $.parseJSON({&#39;key&#39;: 0}) . And raise Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Answer (score 0):

You may have troubles with `'` character trying to run `var groups = "{{ groups|safe }}";` or `var groups = '{{ groups|safe }}';`.
If both answers don't work try this solution:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}

var str = "{{ groups|safe }}";
var new_str = replaceAll(str, "'", "\"");

var groups = JSON.parse(new_str);
```

I had to replace all `'` to `"` in the dictionary for `JSON.parse` to work. To know more about these functions check Stack [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) question.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for this,

In view:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

...
groups = {
'g_1': [
    {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}, 
    {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}
], 
'g_2': [
    {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}, 
    {'name': 'something', 'id': '1'}
]
}
...
return render(request=request,
          template_name=self.template_name,
          context={'groups' : json.dumps(groups, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),})
```

In Template:

```
var groups = {{groups|safe}};
```

[Info on DjangoJSONEncoder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/)